# Bower Segmentation fault (Core dumped)

Tags: 18.04, nodejs, npm

Hi I have just installed nodejs and npm on my Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to install mirador as per installation instructions here: https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/wiki/Getting-Started

When I try to install bower I am getting a segmentation error. Any idea how I can resolve it. Both nodejs and npm are installed successfully as I have tried to get their version and it is returned

Comment: if you haven't solved your problem this might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/507855/bower-install-does-nothing-not-even-throw-an-error#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install npm with bower](https://askubuntu.com/q/759797/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by uninstalling NPM & nodejs then reinstalling.

Then I had to hash bower:

```
hash -d bower
```

Then I just set the permissions to npm and it sorted it

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```